# How to fix this line shape file?

Tags: r, gis, arcgis, shapefile

I am creating a line from point shapefile which is auto generated. First time when I create that line in ArcGIS, I got a line like this because the points are not in a order:
[image]

after that I ordered the points according to it's location and got a line like this:[image]
But unable to create a line like this:
[image]

Please give me any solution to fix this in ArcGIS or R programming. If you need the shapefile I can provide you.

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: `shp<-shapefile(choose.files())`
`dd1<-coordinates(shp)`
`dd1<-dd[ order(dd[,1],dd[,2]), ]`
`sh<-SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(dd1),ID="1")))` I used this to order the points according to the locations. But failed.

Comment: Try subsetting the lower points and then appending the higher points. The line is drawn sequentially by the order of the points.

Comment: @at80 I am sorry but this can't be done via subset. This is a small part of whole line. This problem is in horizontal direction in some places. Any better solution?

Comment: You should be able change to `order(dd[,2], dd[,1])`. If you order over the `y` coordinate first it should fix the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no bullet proof way to restore the line, as same dataset can obviously represent different lines, so you would need to use some heuristics to do this. What Rafael described is very good top-bottom heuristics if you can reliably detect start and end points.

Another heuristics could be a bottom-up process to stitch nearby segments into a line. Find nearby points for every point, sort and connect the two nearest points. Continue this process, making sure each point has at most two connections, and that there are no loops.

A simpler approach that might just work if the line follows in general some direction is your idea of sorting points. But instead of ordering by x or y coordinate, find a linear approximation of these points, project each point to this straight line, and sort using the coordinate of the projection.

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this would be to treat it as a graph problem.

Create a weighted fully connected graph where the nodes are the points and the edge weight distance between its endpoints. Heuristically identify the “starting” and “ending” points of the line (for example, pick the bottom-leftmost point as start and top-rightmost and end).

Then you can use a shortest path algorithm to generate the order in which you connect the points.